# Align the Header in center

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

**react-navigation: 1.0.0-beta.11**

**react: 16.0.0-alpha.12**

**react-native: 0.47.1**

I'm following the [ReactNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/) tutorial to render the `Header` from a passed prop to the screen.

```
class ChatScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `Chat with ${navigation.state.params.user}`,   // <- Talking bout this
  });
  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Chat with {params.user}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I want the `title` in  `title: Chat with ${navigation.state.params.user}` to appear in the center. How do I style it? I also want change it's color.

I tried this [suggestion](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/253#issuecomment-279841162) but did not work.

Many thanks.

After updating the code, it's aligning to the center but it's not quite the center. It's more to the right. I think it's cause of the arrow to the left, how can I fix it?

[image]

Updated Code:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `${navigation.state.params.name.item.name}`,
    headerTitleStyle: {
    color: '#000',
    textAlign: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`titleStyle` property has been rename to `headerTitleStyle` You can now style you header title via `headerTitleStyle` by passing it to navigation options.

```
....
headerTitleStyle: {
      color: 'color value',
      textAlign: 'center',
      alignSelf: 'center' //if style using flexbox
}
....
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it, but there's a small problem. After updating the code, it's aligning to the center but it's not quite the center. It's more to the right. I think it's cause of the arrow to the left, how can I fix it? I updated the screenshot in my question. Can you please help me with this? Many thanks.

Comment: @Somename yes this is due to back button, You can fix it by hiding it `headerLeft: null` in navigation option. or place an other button on right side. if you don't want to place a button on right side you can assign `marginRight: 40` to `headerTitleStyle`

Comment: the way I handled this (I also have a `headerLeft`) is setting `textAlign` and applying `flex:5/6`.

Answer (score 2):

If your screen has ***headerLeft*** or ***Back button***,

```
headerTitleStyle: {
  textAlign: "center",
  alignSelf: "center"
}
```

is not enough to make center title.
You have to use `headerRight: (<View></View>)` to appear at center.

```
 static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitleStyle: {
      textAlign: "center",
      alignSelf: "center"
    }
    headerRight: <View><View />
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

According to **[React Navigation 5.x](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headertitlealign)**

you have to use ***headerTitleAlign*** to center the title. In android, its value is by default **left**, and in iOS its value is **center**.

```
<Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName='Welcome'
  screenOptions={{
    headerTitleStyle: {
      color: 'white',
      fontSize: 20,
    },
    headerTitleAlign: 'center',
  }}
>
  <Stack.Screen name='Welcome' component={Welcome}/>
</Stack.Navigator>
```

More Details: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headertitlealign