# react native Navigation - Custom Nav Bar is not centralized

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

Custom nav bar is not centralised when there is a right navigation icon. The whole custom navigation is pushed left

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. add a custom Nav Bar
2. add an navigation right icon

result: the whole custom navigation area is pushed to the left

ANY HELP?

Comment: Maybe it is same with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699163/align-the-header-in-center/47469915#47469915

Comment: share your nav bar code with the styles.
This probably because of improper use of flex box

Comment: i found the issue, it was a bug in the RNN am using. it was solved after upgrading to latest